# is it uniform distribution HBC ORACLE HISTOGRAME?

Tags: oracle, histogram, uniform-distribution

We have this data : Table R(A,..) with attribute A, nbLine of R is 1000, distinct value for A are 500.

```
data are displayed like this : bucket -> end_point_value.
1  -> 800
2  -> 900
3  -> 1000
4  -> 1200
5 -> 1500
6 ->  2000
7 -> 2300
8 -> 2400
9 -> 2550
10 -> 2590
```

the question is : Does this histogram confirm or deny the hypothesis of a uniform distribution uniform?

I think I can not confirm nor deny, what do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

First you must ask, which *histogram type* is defined on the column.

Oracle provides four different [histogram types](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_histo.htm#TGSQL-GUID-FFA0C0AF-3761-4829-995E-9AFA524F96CE) and is you want to claim about uniform distribution the `frequency` histogram must be defined.

The frequency histogram has one bucket for each distinct value (stored in `ENDPOINT_VALUE` and the frequency is (additive) stored in the column `ENDPOINT_NUMBER`)

So if you histogram has only 10 buckets (as you show in the data) you are ready and you can say nothing about the distribution.

**Example of a Uniform Distribution**

```
create table r as
select
1 + trunc((rownum-1)/2) A
from dual connect by level <= 1000;

select count(*), count(distinct a), min(a), max(a) from r;

  COUNT(*) COUNT(DISTINCTA)     MIN(A)     MAX(A)
---------- ---------------- ---------- ----------
      1000              500          1        500
```

**Create FREQUENCY Histogram with 500 Buckets**

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname=>user, tabname=>'R', method_opt=>'for all columns size 500');

select NUM_BUCKETS, HISTOGRAM from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'R';

NUM_BUCKETS HISTOGRAM      
----------- ---------------
        500 FREQUENCY   

select ENDPOINT_VALUE, ENDPOINT_NUMBER from user_histograms where table_name = 'R' order by ENDPOINT_VALUE;        
 
 ENDPOINT_VALUE, ENDPOINT_NUMBER
1                   2
2                   4
3                   6
4                   8 
...
498                 996
499                 998
500                 1000
```

Comment: now, i think it  deny the hypothesis, because we have 500 distinct value for attribut A, so if it uniforme we should have 2 apperance for each value, so 50 distinct value per bucket (becausse 100 values for each bucket : 1000 nbLines). look at the bucket 10 they can have only 40 distincts values, so it impossible to be uniforme distribution. what do you think ?

Comment: Please reread the answer. Without knowing  the **histogram type** you can say nothing about the histogram data. The interpretation is type dependent.

Comment: it a height balanced histogram.